# What is the meaning of "Gift und Dolch" (in Mozart's Opera Die Entführung aus dem Serail)

Tags: translation, german-to-english, phrase, archaism

Osmin, one of the characters in this Opera said this phrase multiple times.

```
Gift und Dolch
```

For example in [here](https://www.opera-arias.com/mozart/die-entf%C3%BChrung-aus-dem-serail/sie-macht-auf-herr/)

```
OSMIN
Gift und Dolch! was ist das? wer kann ins Haus steigen?
```

Another example in [here](https://www.opera-arias.com/mozart/die-entf%C3%BChrung-aus-dem-serail/z%C3%A4rtlichkeit-schmeicheln/):

```
OSMIN
Gift und Dolch über das Mädchen! - Beym Mahomet! sie macht mich rasend.
```

I know it literally means Poison and Dagger, but I think it must relate to something like "Damn it!""Sh*t!", but I couldn't find a clue.

It must be an archaic usage, because there seem to be no discussions about this phrase on the internet now.

Could anyone help explain this phrase? What could be a good translation? If provided with some references, would be more than better.

Comment: "It must be an archaic usage" No, it isn't. I believe it is just his [catch phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catchphrase). The literal translation fits well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: your thought, that it might mean *something like "Damn it!""Sh*t!"* is - for your first quote - absolutely correct. As for the second quote i suppose @user1934428 got it right: two unpleasant things make one even more unpleasant combination.

If the phrase is "archaic" I am not so sure of. It is definitely not used today and I wonder if it ever was. The character Osmin serves as, to say it in modern terms, a "[comic relief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_relief)" in the opera and I suppose this (perhaps made-up) phrase is a device to identify him - similar to "infinity and beyond" for Buzz Lightyear of "Toy Story" fame or "Bazinga!" for Sheldon Cooper from "Big Bang Theory".

Answer (score 3):

To me, *Gift und Dolch* is meant as an replacement for the common phrase *Tod und Teufel*. They probably used that in the libretto to add an “oriental” flair to it — as they likely don't use the same curses as Europeans do, or do they?

Answer (score 2):

Poison and dagger are both unpleasant means to get killed by, and I guess that the "und" is used because two unpleasant things together must be even more unpleasant.

Is it archaic? Perhaps somewhat, as I have never heard it in real life yet, perhaps because daggers are nowadays out of fashion.